# Unable to remove y label on pie chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, series, pie-chart

So I use the code below (commented out parts are other attempts) and it produces a pie chart almost exactly how I wish it, but [as you can see the Has_Frequency doesn't disappear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4PAq.png) This wouldn't be an issue as I could just change the name of the imported Series but it overlays the "several times a year" entry.

```
#plt.pie(imp['Has_Frequency'].value_counts(), labels=imp['Has_Frequency'])
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Test")
Frequenc = imp['Has_Frequency'].value_counts()
Frequenc.plot.pie(y='test',legend=False, autopct='%1.2f%%')
#fig.axes.set_ylabel('')
#plt.show()
```

As shown in the code above I've tried a few methods of setting the y axis but they haven't changed a thing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated in either removing the label or moving it further to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use `plt.ylabel(None)` or if you create a `fig, ax` you can use `ax.set_ylabel`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imp = pd.DataFrame({'Has_Frequency': np.random.choice(list('abcddef'), 1000)})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
ax.set_title('Test')

imp['Has_Frequency'].value_counts().plot.pie(y='test', legend=False, autopct='%1.2f%%', ax=ax)

ax.set_ylabel(None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing thankyou! The fig, ax gives more versatility so I'll use that!

Comment: @CodeErrors And if you want to still keep the label, but move it really far away, you can do that with `ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), labelpad=80)` and adjust the padding.